# How to manually arrange index of Value_counts in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, group-by, seaborn

I want to get a bar graph according to the value counts of months in my data. When I plot the graph I am getting it in the descending order of values. But I want the graph to be according to the month i.e., the first bar for January, second for February and so on.

**Code**

```
months = df_Badge.Date.dt.month_name().value_counts()
sns.barplot(months.index, months.values, alpha=0.8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if possible some months are missing is possible use [ordered categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) with all categories in list of months:

```
months = ['January','February','March','April',
          'May','June','July','August',
          'September','October','November','December']


months = df_Badge.Date.dt.month_name().value_counts()

months.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(months.index, ordered=True, categories=months)
months = months.sort_index()

sns.barplot(months.index, months.values, alpha=0.8)
```

If all months in index is possible use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), if some month is missing is added with missing value:

```
months = ['January','February','March','April',
          'May','June','July','August',
          'September','October','November','December']

months = df_Badge.Date.dt.month_name().value_counts().reindex(months)
sns.barplot(months.index, months.values, alpha=0.8)
```